# serving flash policy file requests on different port

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets, websocket, adobe

I have changed the default port 843 and instead choose an arbitrary port like 9999 as an argument to `Security.loadPolicyFile` . I have run the policy file server to listen on 9999. It serves well. My question is will the request still will be first to port 843, then to 9999 ? If so, how to force the first request to my desired port, say 9999 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have got my answer from this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html). It summarizes like this:

> Flash Player checks the destination of the loadPolicyFile() only after
>   it has checked the master policy file on port 843 for permission to
>   acknowledge other policy files. If the developer has not specified a
>   loadPolicyFile() command, then Flash Player checks the destination
>   port of the connection.